# Searching another object to compare a value in will_paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
@community_topics = CommunityTopic.page(params[:page]).order('updated_at DESC').where(["username = ?", params[:search]])
```

This is how I would normally paginate the community topics user I am searching because I can directly check if the username is equal to the searched parameters but in this case specifically what is stored is the user_id and not a string I cant just compare. Been a few months since I coded rails so I'm pretty sure I'm missing some simple way with associations and would appreciate guidance in the right direction.

Sorry if I'm overlooking something stupid. Its going over my head for some reason.

Comment: I'd like to do something like the following where I'm directly checking if the associated ID's username parameter is equal to the searched parameter     @community_topics = CommunityTopic.page(params[:page]).order('updated_at DESC').where(user.username: params[:search])

Comment: How is `CommunityTopic` related to `User`? Can you share the Models in the question?

Comment: CommunityTopics are created by Users and the User is considered the owner using belong_to to associate http://pastebin.com/QyzMr0SK

Comment: Also, what is the Rails version you using?

Comment: What do you get in params[:search]? username or user_id?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are **passing username in params[:search]**. Update your query as below:

```
@community_topics = CommunityTopic.joins(:user).order(updated_at: :desc).where("users.username = ?", params[:search]).page(params[:page])
```

If you are **passing user_id in params[:search]**. Update your query as below:

```
@community_topics = CommunityTopic.joins(:user).order(updated_at: :desc).where("users.username = ?", User.find(params[:search]).username).page(params[:page])
```